# Remove [programming-languages]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Not completely, as [stated by Dukeling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254173). I'll edit some questions to remove some [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) in questions, that do ask about one language, not about programming languages overall.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to repurpose the tag to the development of programming-languages.  Or perhaps that's its original intention.

Comment: The tag-wiki *currently* claims it applies to programming language design. That said the wiki could use some work.

Comment: Any question about programming language _design_ is pretty much _ex officio_ too broad.

Comment: And any specific question relating to programming language design is likely to be a much better fit for the Computer Science stackexchange

Comment: Just removing the tag isn't enough. Nearly all of the questions should join it in the fire.

Comment: If the tag is about programming language design, it should be called `programming-language-design`. And it seems like a bad tag to have regardless, as it will likely lead to various fuzzy, opinion-based discussions. So indeed it seems like a useless, confusing tag that needs deletion.

Comment: Also, [tag:computer-science]

Comment: I don't think that removing those tags and related questions will result in anything good. I mean there's a reason for them to exist, and if they wouldn't someone would just recreate them.

Comment: @Theolodis that means we shouldn't delete any tags. People create wrong tags, because they don't quite understand what kind of questions are on-topic for SO. Those wrong tags needs to be removed. `programming-languages` and `computer-science` are 2 of those wrong tags.

Comment: Please don't just remove the tag from questions. Most of the questions I see out the most recent 50 need to be closed. The rest of them probably aren't much better. This is going to require a lot of clean-up.

Comment: @nicael, I've noticed you in the suggested edit queue suggesting a lot of edits removing programming-languages. While some of these questions are wrongly tagged, as Dukeling's answer said there should probably be more retagging then straight-out removal. Some of your suggested removals used the tag just as it is supposed to be. In addition, you often only edit tags and don't address the mess that some of these questions have.

Comment: @connor But I won't be edit-banned? If my edits are wrong you can always reject them. I am removing [programing-languages] at this moment, no more. 59 accepted edits for 32 minutes.

Comment: @nicael I'm just suggesting to be more careful with your edits, and if there are other problems with the post, make sure to fix those too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There should probably be a fair amount of retagging and closing, not straight-out removal.

- Language design questions should be tagged [language-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design).
- A few of the questions should probably be tagged [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).
- [language-comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-comparisons) would presumably apply to a few of them, but that seems like a worse tag (next on our burninate list?).
- Almost everything else should probably be closed.

  [Here's a direct link to start reviewing those close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=programming-languages) (for 3k+ users).

[But a lot of the language tags should probably go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254210/clean-up-the-language-tags).

Comment: I saw it used once as "this is a ridiculously small programming language I spotted, and I want to talk about it".  So small a tag environment isn't reasonable.  Possibly [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209498/most-impressive-creation-with-kodu) should be closed?

Comment: I suspect that [tag:language-comparisons] should go; any good question tagged with it is likely to be better on Programmers.SE, as answers would likely be somewhat subjective and long.