# Clean up the [*language*] tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request, synonym-request

Building on [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254102/remove-programming-languages), I just noticed that plenty of the language tags are pretty useless.

- [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) (x279) - use [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) when referring to natural languages instead, or is there a need to have a tag for questions not about natural languages that aren't about natural language processing?
- [language-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-theory) (x77) - I wouldn't even know what types of questions this is for. We should probably use more specific tags. Perhaps use [language-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design) in some cases.
- [language-comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-comparisons) (x90) - mostly too broad, probably typically don't make questions with lasting value.
- [language-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-binding) (x21) - not sure about this one.
- [language-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design) (x904) - I originally thought this is a decent tag, but now I'm not sure any more. My guess is that most questions that uses this tag appropriately would fit better on Computer Science or Programmers.

Too broad - use specific language tags in favour of these:

- [scripting-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting-language) (x169)
- [formal-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-languages)? (x151)
- [dynamic-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-languages) (x141)
- [intermediate-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intermediate-language) (x73)
- [embedded-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-language) (x74)
- [esoteric-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esoteric-languages) (x38)
- [jvm-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvm-languages) (x120)
- [compiled-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiled-language) (x15)
- [concatenative-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenative-language) (x11)
- [graphical-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphical-language) (x5)
- [imperative-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imperative-languages) (x7)
- [interpreted-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreted-language) (x82)

Possibly useful, but hopelessly too broad: (I doubt anyone can be an expert in any of these)

- [language-specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-specifications) (x49) (unless it's actually about *writing* and/or reviewing these specifications, which doesn't seem particularly appropriate for Stack Overflow anyway)
- [cross-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-language) (x54)
- [language-construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-construct) (x37)
- [language-concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-concepts) (x18)
- [language-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-extension) (x29)
- [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) (x680) - sounds like some specific tool or something, but the tag wiki just says it's "about the intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages and environments", i.e. it's essentially the same as [language-specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-specification).

Synonymization:

- [natural-lang-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/natural-lang-programming) (x12) - synonymize with [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) or just retag them.
- [multiple-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages) (x52) - synonymize with [multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage) (x558), assuming we want either of those.
- (while I'm at it) [java-language-spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-language-spec) - synonymize with [jls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jls).

**If you disagree with anything...**

It would probably be best to post an answer with a single point, as to make it easy for people to show agreement or disagreement with individual points.

---

Feel free to point out if I missed one.

Comment: For `language-lawyer`, see [this previous discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142058/135887).  Despite how generic a term it is, it's actually useful as-is for the C++ folks.

Comment: [tag:keyboard-language] -> [tag:locale] ?

Comment: Are we supposed to answer if we agree on a specific point? I am definitely +1 for merging [tag:java-language-spec] and [tag:jls].

Comment: @JohnY I don't know. Probably not. The JLS one is pretty clear-cut IMO. The idea is to upvote if you agree on some, and point out those that you don't agree with in the answers, but I guess that isn't perfect because that assumes everyone has opinions on all of them. I guess I was just to lazy to split this into 27 different questions.

Comment: The problem is that tags do not exist for _all_ languages. This forces users to use more generic tags (i.e. `esoteric-languages` instead of `befunge`).

Comment: `keyboard-language` -> `input-language`?

Comment: There is also keyboard-layout

Comment: Clean up your language* young man!

Comment: Personally, I like the esoteric-languages tag. Once I start looking at one, I inevitably become interested in others.

Comment: Pretty sure `intermediate-language` represents the language used when compiling, so there would actually be two "specific language tags", but you may be asking a question specifically about that third, intermediate language. I know .NET IL is supposed to use `cil`, but nobody really uses that abbreviation AFAIK; I've always seen IL.

Answer (score 27):

You need to be very careful here, as there's a whole load of different tags and different usages. *The right action for one is not necessarily the right action for another.*

Let's look at some extremes.

- The [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) tag needs clearing out. There's no coherence; it's all over the place. Drain that swamp! Make some alligator handbags!
- The [concatenative-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenative-language) can probably stay, at least for the moment, as the questions in it appear to be at least reasonably on topic for such a thing. (I'd never heard of the term before, but it does seem to be a clear concept.)
- You're right that [java-language-spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-language-spec) and [jls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jls) look like synonyms. But which way is best? I'm inclined to say that it's actually [jls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jls) that should go, despite it being the more widely used tag at the moment; it might be a term well known to some, but the other one is going to be *more* widely known and there'll be no harm.

I'm inclined to say that it's only worth putting effort in to getting rid of a tag if there's enough disagreement over the meaning to make it unclear what it means. Or if every question tagged with it is closed as off-topic.

We need to remember that the purpose of a tag is two-fold:

1. To make the question easier for computers (especially search engines of various kinds) to understand. This improves the overall value of the site; this is absolutely fundamental.
2. To provide a basis for people to observe just part of a site. I subscribe to some tags, keeping an eye on them and trying to answer questions in them.

If a tag is single-topic (according to a consensus of *human* interpretation) and worth having good open questions in, it's worth keeping. Because of that, I think you should un-ask this question and instead ask a number of more focused questions. After all, you have no idea what the voting on this question is in favour of.

---

**Bad questions are just bad questions.** Fix 'em or close 'em, but don't waste effort fiddling around with just the tagging on them as that (probably) won't make them be good questions.

Comment: Agreed that most of the tags seem reasonable.  I actually do think "JLS" is more widely recognized than "java-language-spec", though; I've never before seen the "Java language" part spelled out without the "specification" part spelled out as well.

Answer (score 19):

The [natural-lang-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/natural-lang-programming) tag is very definitely **not** the same as [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) (NLP is natural language *processing*). The former is about programming languages designed to be like natural language. Or to put it another way, striving to use natural language *as* a programming language. The latter is about using computers (typically with traditional programming languages) to process natural language.

So, while it's definitely a small niche, it's not a good candidate for synonymization.

Comment: I cleaned up the questions where this tag was misapplied to refer to natural language processing. However, while it doesn't make a good synonym, I question whether it's useful on SO. Any question I can think of where a tag about natural language programming in general (as opposed to a tag for some specific language implementing the idea) would be better suited for CS or Programmers than it is for SO. Most of the questions where it's already being used correctly are rightfully closed.

Comment: Could be an appropriate tag, in theory, but there's just a lack of appropriate questions. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262597/why-no-programming-in-english-what-is-the-difference-between-natural-languages) is the only one with that tag (of the open 5 remaining...) that might have some potential, but even that would be better suited on Programmers. Agreed that we shouldn't synonymize them.

Answer (score 7):

I think the [language-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-theory) tag is accurate, but most of the questions so tagged appear more suited to cs.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) is a mess. It's definitely **not** convertible to [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp). Some folks use [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) to indicate that they are talking about multiple programming languages (e.g. trying to choose among them, or issues surrounding the use of multiple programming languages for a single application). Some folks use the tag to mean they are dealing with internationalization or locale issues. I suspect it's actually uncommon to use this tag when [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) is meant, because folks who do NLP tend to know the [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) tag.

So, I guess the main alternatives here are to burninate [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/languages) (too loosely used to be meaningful, and just intrinsically vague) or to manually review the questions and retag as appropriate.

Comment: @smci: Y'know, I didn't mean for those to be tags, otherwise I would have done it myself. I would like to be able to use regular English prose and just speak in plain sentences with plain words, thank you.

Comment: John Y: sorry, just 'internationalization','locale' are already tags. It seemed clearer to me to write them as such.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with most of your suggestions, but [formal-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-languages) (which you mark with a "?") is unrelated and should stay. (Many of these questions are on the fuzzy border between stackoverflow, cs-theory, math, and cs.) In particular, it does not refer to an unspecified class of programming languages but to "formal" languages as defined in logic. (It's actually closer to [regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions) than any of the language tags.)

Answer (score 4):

[language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) is used when you are interested in the theory behind some particular (often obscure) language detail, which may not have any practical use.

For example, if you would post a question about how the expression `i+++++i` is interpreted by a C compiler, then [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) is appropriate as an explanation of why you post such strange code. If not for the tag, people would just reply "don't write crap like this, it is bad practice/it doesn't make any sense" etc.

The tag could certainly do with a better description however. I also agree that it may possibly be synonymous with [language-specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-specification).

Comment: Your example would be better written as `i+++++j`.

Comment: I find language-lawyer a very bad description for this case. If you're interested in corner-cases of a programming language, just use something like language specification.

Answer (score 2):

"Too broad - use specific language tags in favour of these"

That's fine provided they already exist. I'd recommend keeping at least a couple "inferior tags" (as [BradleyDotNET called them in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283027/what-tag-to-use-for-question-in-a-new-programming-language)) for questions by sub-1500s about programming languages that happen not to have a tag on SO yet. Perhaps they can be cut down to [scripting-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting-language) and [compiled-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiled-language).