# Clarification needed for meta tag [languages]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

<sub>Side note: there is a SO [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) which should be burned (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254210) and go ahead torch wielders!), but I actually meant meta as "meta.stackoverflow.com", not what you probably thought I meant. Sorry!</sub>

The tag [english](/questions/tagged/english) has a tag excerpt (hover to read it), and is very clearly defined. So I was confused when someone edited [languages](/questions/tagged/languages) into my question. It seems to be used sometimes instead of [english](/questions/tagged/english), and sometimes to mean *programming* language(s).

I think that it *should* mean "programming languages" because that seems to be an important enough part of our site (in case you forgot). Can it be renamed? Or else what?

The other thing that I wanted to point out is that I think that [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) should become a synonym of *something*. Maybe [design](/questions/tagged/design), which is synonymous with HTML and CSS. The only JS questions on topic on meta are about how JS works on SO, but the tag is just too easy to misuse.

Comment: Would a tag `languages` which refers to programming languages actually be useful? The fact that they're posting on SO immediately means that the question is related to programming languages. It would appear to me `languages` should only mean human languages. `English` has a terrible description - for the use of English and *other languages*.. What?

Comment: @Laurel: I'm sorry for confusing you with the tag I added ;) Anyway, I would follow the argumentation given by Rob. But you are right, as long as there is no tag excerpt/info, the usage of the `languages` tag is unclear.

Comment: @Laurel: So tempted to add the `languages` tag to this question as well... ;)